# Android App for smart modification of calendar events

Tags: gratis, android, calendar

I am looking for an Android app which can check my calendar events, scan the text for specific keywords and then perform actions based on the keyword, e.g. add a reminder to this event.

Example: I want to get notified for events with the keyword "disco". In a shared calendar, a friend creates an event: "Going to disco" so the app should add a reminder for this event which reminds me in the morning that my friends are going to disco in the evening.

Answer (score 1):

Yo, another one to be answered with **[Tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info)**:

*Tasker* is the most complex and mighty automation tool available for Android, which even can handle your car and stereo (given some extras). You can setup a "Profile"<sup>1</sup> watching your calendar and reacting on keywords found in the descriptions (oh, you can do the same for mails and short-messages, by the way). As it also can create calendar events (or send messages), creating a reminder should be easy to do.

As *Tasker* doesn't come for free (it's about USD 5, but worth every cent) and has a steep learning curve (the [linked tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) also contains links to tutorials and more, make sure to check those), you might wish to first pick the 7-day trial from their project site. All details for that can be found in the mentioned tag-wiki at our Android sister-site – where you also can find further help with *Tasker* if needed.

---

<sup>**1:** For *Tasker,* a "profile" is a combination of a "condition" (event, state) with a "task" (action to perform)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I downloaded the Tasker trial version some months ago, because I was dissatisfied with Llama App, but because of the learning curve I dismissed it. Now, with a new problem, I will check it again.

Comment: Trick to keep in mind: On end of day 6, export your config and profiles. Uninstall Tasker, install it again, import your saved config and profiles. Gets you another 7 days trial. This part is a hint given by the dev himself, the following is a conclusion by me: "Repeat until done – but don't forget to buy the app when decided" :) – oh, btw: And take a look at my [collection of Tasker resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) for tutorials, plugins, etc :)